# Next.js Disabling file-system routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

According to the documentation  [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) setting the **useFileSystemPublicRoutes** configuration option to false prevents routing based on files in /pages directory. But i cant understand what it really does because they dont elaborate much.

I will appreciate it if someone could explain it to me with simple examples of what this config does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`useFileSystemPublicRoutes` set to `false` does only one thing - disables built-in server-side routing.

For example, let's say you have two pages:

- `/pages/foo.js`
- `/pages/bar.js`

By default, upon build Next.js will register two routes:

- `example.com/foo`
- `example.com/bar`

When `useFileSystemPublicRoutes` set to `false` these two routes won't be created at server side, so a user can't access it by typing `example.com/foo` in browser URL bar.

However, client-side navigation still can access these routes if you use `next/link` or `next/router`.

You don't need to use `useFileSystemPublicRoutes` config unless you have a custom server and Next.js routes that were registered based on the `pages` directory interfere with it.